# How to reset JLabel constraints after initializing it?

Tags: java, swing, constraints, reset, jlabel

I initialize a JLabel in Java frame like this :

```
contentPane.add(myLabel, cc.xywh(1, 1, 31, 6, CellConstraints.DEFAULT, CellConstraints.BOTTOM));
```

But before showing the JFrame i make a small condition which if returns true i want to set myLabel to be set to DEFAULT instead of BOTTOM, but i can't find anyway except redefining it again like this :

```
contentPane.add(myLabel, cc.xywh(1, 1, 31, 6));
```

**So is there a better way to just edit the vertical location property ?**

Comment: What is your layout on the contentPane ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a jgoodies `FormLayout`, you are somewhat restricted in the reuse of your `CellConstraints` instances.  It appears from the documentation and examples that each component is added to the panel and the `CellConstraints` instances are copied.  Further, when trying to gather the constraints for the current component, a *copy* of the `CellConstraints` is returned.  However, you do have an option:  you can take that copy of the `CellConstraints`, modify the public `vAlign` instance var and then call `setConstraints` on your `FormLayout` with this updated constraints set.

```
FormLayout layout = (FormLayout)contentPane.getLayout(); 
cc = layout.getConstraints(myLabel);
cc.vAlign = CellConstraints.DEFAULT;
layout.setConstraints(myLabel, cc);
```

It is a little bit more verbose than the simple re-add that you have provided, but it removes the need to maintain the magic numbers (1,1,31,6) in your original instance.

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to do ... Instead of being restricted to the cell coordinates (1,1,31,6) ... Thanks a lot :)